# need access to Class Object via Function Pointer - Binary Search Tree Class Creation Related

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Creating Traversals for Binary Search Tree with Recursion.

```
void inOrder(void (*inOrderPtr)(T&)) 
{ 
    if(this->left != NULL) 
        inOrder((*inOrderPtr)(this->left)); 
    inOrderPtr(this->data); 
    if(this->right != NULL) 
        inOrder((*inOrderPtr)(this->right)); 
}
```

Here is the function.  Now this is obviously wrong.  This function is called like this:

```
first.inOrder(print_vals);
```

first is the object, and print vals is simply a function that prints what is the data in the object.  There are three values for each object, data, left, and right.  How do I actually access those items with the function?

Comment: Using the "code sample" template along with some newlines and indentation would make this code sample a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the call to `inOrderPtr(this->data)` is passing just the `data` member of the tree node to the `print_vals` function. If you would like to access the `left` and `right` elements, use `inOrderPtr(*this)`. You will have to change various declarations in order for this to compile, such as the declarations for `inOrderPtr` and `print_vals`. Without seeing the rest of your code it's hard to say what you need to change them to.

On another note, it seems to me that you might want to write the recursive calls more like this:

```
this->left->inOrder(inOrderPtr);
```

I am making assumptions about your implementation, though.

Comment: http://rafb.net/p/aBmQZx94.html this is actually the driver program.  I can't change any of that so I have to kind of follow the guide.

Comment: Ok this actually worked, and on top of the fact that did not put in BT<T>:: in front of void which was my dumb mistake.  Thanks for the help! :) and I apologize for making it kind of messy, just heard about this site.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to click the "accept answer" link if this was helpful! :)